# Find and scp in one command

Tags: linux, find

I need to scp all txt files in /home/data directory and its subdirectories.

```
find /home/data/ -type f -name *.txt -exec scp {} user@ip:/home/testdir \;
```

The command seemed to work but on the destination server instead of a folder there was a file named testdir and it seemed to have the size of the last txt file that was transfered.

Am I missing something in the command?

Comment: Do you have a `/home/testdir` folder on your remote server ? If not, `scp` command will not create it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rsync may be more appropriate for the task. It has very handy include and exclude flags. You can use it like so:

```
rsync -rav -e ssh --include '*/' --include='*.txt' --exclude='*' \
    server:/usr/folders/ \ /usr/backup/
```

Comment: Will it search in subdirectories as well?

Comment: @Andy Rsync can do recursive directories, you will just need to use the correct argument. Refer to the man page for this.